# JQuery click event not working on links with # - need to show / hide submenus on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a left hand menu that has a flyout submenu on hover. On tablet / mobile I have the menu collapsing with a toggle button. This all works fine.

The problem is the click event does not work on the menu items that have a submenu. I need to show / hide the submenus on click on mobile.  So nothing happens when Item 1 is clicked but item 2 works and the submenu links work. Could it be the ones with links work and the ones with # don't?

```js
   $(function() {
//behaviours depending on screensize
function checkScreenSize() {
  var width = $(window).width();

  /*MOBILE*/
  if (width < 991.98) {
    $('#primary-menu li').click(function() {
      console.log('test 1');
      $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    });
    //does not work

    $('#primary-menu > li').on('click', function() {
      console.log('test 2');
      $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    });
    //does not work

    //show submenu 
    $('#primary-menu  li').on('click', function() {
      console.log('test 3');
      var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
      $(submenu).show();

    });
    //does not work

    $('#primary-menu li > .sub-menu').parent().click(function() {
      console.log('test 4');
      var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
      var current = $(this).hasClass("current-menu-item");
      $(submenu).show();

    });
    //this works

  } else {
    /*DESKTOP*/
    // ....this all works....
  }


  checkScreenSize();
  $(window).resize(checkScreenSize);
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-4793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4793">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/copie.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Item 1</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: table;">
      <li id="menu-item-4908" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4908">
        <a href="/subitem1/">SUBItem1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-4892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4892">
        <a href="/subitem2/">SUBItem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-4794">
    <a href="/item2/" aria-current="page" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">
      <img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy">
      <span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Item 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to getting it working, but using non-link anchor tags for dropdowns is bad for accessibility. Consider using a more semantic [button pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-links.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but Im not sure thats possible with the navigation in wordpress.

Comment: It's possible. You'd need to create a [custom menu walker](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function mobileInit() {
    $('li.menu-item').off("click").click(function(e) {
      if ($(this).parent("ul").is("#primary-menu")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Click Event on Top Level");
        $(".sub-menu", this).toggle();
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log("Click Event on Sub Level");
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  function desktopInit() {}

  //behaviours depending on screensize
  function checkScreenSize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 991.98) {
      console.log("Mobile");
      mobileInit();
    } else {
      console.log("Desktop");
      desktopInit();
    }
  }

  checkScreenSize();
  $(window).resize(checkScreenSize);
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-4793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4793">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/copie.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Item 1</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4908" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4908">
        <a href="/subitem1/">SUBItem1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-4892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4892">
        <a href="/subitem2/">SUBItem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-4794">
    <a href="/item2/" aria-current="page" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">
      <img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy">
      <span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Item 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This assumes the User will click on all the `menu-item` elements and we want to do different things depending on their location in the hierarchy.

> The **stopPropagation()** method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed. If you want to stop those behaviors, see the [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method. It also does not prevent immediate propagation to other event-handlers. If you want to stop those, see [stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation).

**Update**

You had a Style, `display: table` on your  element. Removing this allows CSS to Show and Hide it as needed. Switching to `.toggle()` will do this.

Comment: It seems to behave in exactly the same way as my original code and therefore does not work.  The subitem does not show when the parent li is selected.

Comment: @LeeTee then please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Since you did not include the Styling or CSS, I have no way to know whats happening in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding everything but its not functioning...Ill  try again

Comment: What we need is you to post the relevant CSS in your example in the question (aka **OP** or **O**riginal **P**ost).

Comment: @LeeTee applied an update to the answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, but this is still not working in real life project in wordpress, I can only assume there is another problem causing this.  Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: Its nothing to do wiht the CSS though, as mentione din original message, there is no event firing on click for the items with a submenu but works for everything else.

Comment: @LeeTee that does not make any sense so I am assuming some other WP Library or Styling interfering. You will need to update your OP so that it is a better example or examine things further.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I hadnt realised there was some javascript already included in the base wordpress theme for the navigation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try event delegation method, for example something like this;

```
$('#primary-menu).on('click', '.submenu > .menu-item', function (e) {
  // avoid the event to propagate and avoid running the other event listeners added to parent element(s)
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do the stuff you want to do with sub menus
  var submenu = $(this).children('.sub-menu');
  $(submenu).show();
})

$('#primary-menu).on('click', '.menu-item.menu-item-has-children', function (e) {
  // avoid the event to propagate and avoid running the other event listeners added to child element(s)
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do the stuff you want to do with menu items that has sub menus
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add two class to target directly your `<li>` (or work with your ids) ?
I just add class `menu-item-toggler` to the first item and `menu-item-redirect`  the the second one.
Then I work with these classes.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for

```js
$(function() {
  function mobileInit() {
    $('.menu-item-toggler').click(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Click Event on Top Level");
        $('.menu-item-toggler>.sub-menu').toggle();
        return false;
    })
    $('.menu-item-redirect').click(e => {
        console.log("Click Event on Sub Level");
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    })
  };
  function desktopInit() {}

  //behaviours depending on screensize
  function checkScreenSize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 991.98) {
      console.log("Mobile");
      mobileInit();
    } else {
      console.log("Desktop");
      desktopInit();
    }
  }

  checkScreenSize();
  $(window).resize(checkScreenSize);
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
  <li id="menu-item-4793" class="menu-item-toggler menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4793">
    <a href="#" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered"><img width="1" height="1" src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/copie.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy"><span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Item 1</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-4908" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4908">
        <a href="/subitem1/">SUBItem1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-4892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4892">
        <a href="/subitem2/">SUBItem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-4794" class="menu-item-redirect menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-4794">
    <a href="/item2/" aria-current="page" class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-not-hovered">
      <img width="1" height="1" src="https://staging.heuristic-hypatia.91-134-228-53.plesk.page/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Plan-de-travail-1.svg" class="menu-image menu-image-title-after" alt="" loading="lazy">
      <span class="menu-image-title-after menu-image-title">Item 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*I worked with Twisty's code